# request body gets lost when using all() routing in Express

Tags: express

So i just discovered that i can't pass `req.body` as expected when doing things like this:

#### Serverside

```
  app.all('*',users.authCheck);

  app.post('/shipments/create', shipments.create);
```

#### Clientside

```
return $http.post('/express/shipments/create',{
            shipment: this.data,
        });
```

`req.body` is shown as empty at `users.authCheck`
I sniffed around a bit and read about `bodyParser` middleware, but can't figure out how i could pass my request body to the create route

How would one solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your client code you're posting to `/express/shipments/create` but on your server side you're receiving to `/shipments/create` which might be causing error. You can use bodyparser like this:

```
app.configure(function () {
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
});
```

Comment: Nope, the path is correct. Also, i did include the bodyParser middleware already. I just have no idea how i could actually use it now

Comment: did you mean you want to get the post data in your server?

Comment: I need access to the data in req.body in `shipments.create`

Comment: you can get it by the parameters names or IDs like req.body.username. Also you can do this with req.param('username').

Comment: Sure enough. But req.body isn't even available on `shipments.create`, even if i have included the bodyParser middleware. Do i have to call something in order to pass it?

Comment: What is shipments.create? Does this has arguments req, res when it gets called?

Comment: Yes, it's a regular routing method. Thank you for your efforts, i'm going to drop `app.all()` and implement the authCheck directly into each route

Comment: I had the same problem when I was importing the routes from a different .js file. You're welcome though

Comment: First, check if the `form` in page is using `method="post"`, check if all inputs you want are inside the form, check if all inputs have `name` property.